# Maven rebuild failure of tests, build does not complete

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea

I have a large project that I am working on. I recently checked out our evolution branch, did a git pull and tried to deploy the app locally.  It doesn't seem to recognize some libraries or jars in one Java class, so subsequently errors halt me from running. Basically, the import statements go unrecognized in the class.

Turns out I forgot to rebuild maven. When I ran mvn clean install from the command prompt, the build fails (even when I do mvn clean install -fn) as there are tests that fail.  I don't often work with maven, or the command line, but here is my full stack trace when I run mvn clean install -e: [image: here]
I'm running my project in the IntelliJ environment.
When I ran mvn clean install -fn, 'talent-app' was successful, but talent-core still failed and I still got

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Please let me know if you have any input, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly.

Basically, regarding your first paragraph, you said you *had* library issues but that after a clean rebuild - of your project, I suppose not of Maven itself - everything is fine?

Regarding the rest of your post, your build is failing because of a failing test case. This is shown by the line:

```
talent-core ............................... FAILURE
```

and by the output:

```
Failed to execute goal [...]. There are test failures.
```

If you go into the `target/surefire-reports` folder, you will find some files containing the output and error traces of each test, including the one that failed.

By scrolling up in your terminal, you should also be able to see which test was failing for talent-core.

From then on, by order of preference:

- either look at the test reports as mentioned in the output, and attempt to figure our why the test is failing, and either fix the test or the code;
- or skip the tests, you can add `-DskipTests` to the command-line. But you shouldn't skip your tests, really.

Comment: No, sorry. I still have issues with the libraries. I still cannot deploy the app because of these errors.  I'm under the impression that I need to rebuild the Maven server so that the jar files get pulled down from git, but I am not sure.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @keslami: not really, or at least not in a traditional project context... There's no such thing as a maven server. There are, however, maven repositories, but you probably have no business building these. You do however *deploy artifacts* to the repositories, and that's where usually your builds will pull dependencies from (and not from git).

Comment: Thank you, -DskipTests allowed the build to complete successfully, but this only rules out that it was not the issue, as I still have problems with the imports.  I'll have to look into this.  I apologize for scrambling

Comment: @keslami: but yes, these errors will prevent the deployment for your project's artifacts. So you'll have to fix the failing test cases. Or, like I said, you can use -DskipTests. Which mean you **might** get a successful build and be able to deploy, and it **might** work as expected, but if the tests are failing it means something in your code is likely broken and you should fix it (or it can be that the test was badly written, and it should be fixed).